# Problem fetching data in ManyToMany and OneToMany relationship using JPA: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

I am working on a small project using **Spring Boot, Hibernate, and JPA**. I have created three entities-

1. Book
2. Author
3. Publication

**Required relationships-**

1. One book can be written by multiple authors and the author can have many books. Therefore- Many to Many Relationship
2. One book can have only one publication and one publication can have many books. Therefore- Many to One Relationship

**The code for these entities-**

1. Book.java-

```
//...import statements

@Entity
@Data
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Book_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Book_name",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String bookName;

    @Column(name = "Publication_date",nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date publishDate;

    @Column(name = "ISBN",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String isbn;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "publication_id", nullable = false)
    private Publication publication;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Book_Author", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "Book_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "Author_id"))
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

}
```

2. Author.java-

```
//... import statements

@Entity
@Data
public class Author {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Author_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="First_name",nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="Last_name",nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="Mobile_number",nullable = false, unique = true,length = 10)
    private long mobileNo;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    Set<Book> books=new HashSet<>();
}
```

3. Publication.java-

```
//... import statements
@Entity
@Data
public class Publication {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="Publication_name",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="Registration_number",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String regNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publication")
    Set<Book> books=new HashSet<>();
}
```

**Problems-** I am facing following issues with the code:

1. In the Many to Many relationship of **Book** and **Author**, when fetching Book or Author, I do not get the corresponding Author and Book respectively. What I get is an  empty set. Example-

```
 @Override
    public BookDto getBook(int id) {
        Book book=this.bookRepository.findById(id).get();
        System.out.println("Book Publisher: "+book.getPublication());
        System.out.println("Author: "+book.getAuthors()); //empty set
        return this.bookToDto(book);
    }
```

**Although, when I use SQL query in MySQL, I get the result-**

```
Select * from demodb.book natural join demodb.book_author natural join demodb.author
```

Also, the Hibernate query shows that the query is being fired on the **join** of the tables to fetch data but nothing is returned in the query.
2. In the Many to One relationship of **Book** and **Publication**, when fetching Publication, the associated set of books is not fetched from the database, although Hibernate query is fired to fetch. But, when fetching a book, publication is fetched.

Query when fetching publication by id- (I am aware that cyclic dependency might occur but the objects are not fetched at all because I get empty **Set** in publication.getBooks())

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.publication_name,
        p1_0.registration_number
    from
        publication p1_0
    where
        p1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.publication_id,
        b1_0.book_id,
        b1_0.book_name,
        b1_0.isbn,
        b1_0.publication_date
    from
        book b1_0
    where
        b1_0.publication_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.publication_id,
        b1_0.book_id,
        b1_0.book_name,
        b1_0.isbn,
        b1_0.publication_date
    from
        book b1_0
    where
        b1_0.publication_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        a1_0.book_id,
        a1_1.author_id,
        a1_1.first_name,
        a1_1.last_name,
        a1_1.mobile_number
    from
        book_author a1_0
    join
        author a1_1
            on a1_1.author_id=a1_0.author_id
    where
        a1_0.book_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.author_id,
        b1_1.book_id,
        b1_1.book_name,
        b1_1.isbn,
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.publication_name,
        p1_0.registration_number,
        b1_1.publication_date
    from
        book_author b1_0
    join
        book b1_1
            on b1_1.book_id=b1_0.book_id
    left join
        publication p1_0
            on p1_0.id=b1_1.publication_id
    where
        b1_0.author_id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        a1_0.book_id,
        a1_1.author_id,
        a1_1.first_name,
        a1_1.last_name,
        a1_1.mobile_number
    from
        book_author a1_0
    join
        book b1_1
            on b1_1.book_id=b1_0.book_id
    left join
        publication p1_0
            on p1_0.id=b1_1.publication_id
    where
        b1_0.author_id=?
```

3. **Error in using FetchType.LAZY in book-publication relationship**-
   When I use **fetch=FetchType.LAZY** on the **publication** in **Book** entity and try to fetch book,

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publication_id", nullable = false)
    private Publication publication;
```

I get the following error-

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.ayushsingh.demojpa.dto.BookDto["publication"]->com.ayushsingh.demojpa.entity.Publication$HibernateProxy$F4hnTR8H["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
```

**Note-**
I am using **ModelMapper 3.1.1, Dev Tools, Java version- 17 and Spring Boot Version- 3.0.6** .
I have clubbed these issues as they might be releated. Please help.